# Available virtual memory size is less then pagefile size

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, pagefile

When Windows runs out of memory commit size it starts showing 'Low memory' window and performs slowly. This low-memory warning is not directly related to free physical memory amount. One can have 7Gb free physical memory but be out of commit memory. This problem is easily solved by setting higher limit of virtual memory size.

Now to the problem:

1. Windows 7 x64 Pagefile is manually allocated at 32Gb in advanced settings
2. `c:/pagefile` is exactly of this size, see this screenshot:

http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_998b13791c71.png

However really allocated virtual memory is showing only 13Gb available and available commit size is 19Gb lower than needed.

How do I fix that and prevent from happening in future? I'm not sure why settings are not properly setting page file size.

Comment: Why on earth would you need 32gb of swapfile in the first place? Once the system starts swapping, you're done anyway.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Because 13Gb is not enough and causing 'low memory' popups even when I still have physical memory available. It is not about physical memory, it is about commit size that is easily eaten my heavy software like Photoshop and virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a 32gb swapfile should be the real question.

> However really allocated virtual memory is showing only 13Gb available
>   and available commit size is 19Gb lower than needed.

Not sure what it is you're asking about here?

I will tell you that statically assigning page file amounts is the better route.  If you have a 32GB Swapfile something else is very wrong.  Is this a personal computer or a workstation built for CAD/SQL?

Comment: This is a development workstation running few virtual machines, development web servers and SQL. My typical memory consumption is 24-27/32 physical RAM. I never exceed physical RAM, but windows wont normally work without swap files. "Not sure what it is you're asking about here?" just see the screenshot. I've statically allocated 32gb but it shows as 13gb.

Comment: The screenshot is super tiny, I can barely read it :(

Comment: Admins have removed original screenshot which was normal size http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_998b13791c71.png